# Dynamics 365 Export Progress Is Stuck

Tags: export-to-excel, crm, microsoft-dynamics

There is no file that gets downloaded when exporting the records from Chrome or Edge. It is stuck to downloading forever.

Business only allows the use of these two browsers.

This is the URL that gets displayed at the bottom of the page.
https://ourcrmorgurl.com/_grid/print/export_progress.aspx?IsExactCountKnown=true&IsExportExcelOnline=false&PageRecordCount=50&dType=1&documentType=1#

[image][image]

Comment: Did you verify any problem in Browser developer toolbar (F12) - Network or console tab ?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the same problem here. (D365 V8.2.28.11 on prem)